# Passing textbox Id in javascript function

Tags: javascript

I want to pass `textbox id` to a javascript function but it returns object event. My code is below:

1] textbox html code

```
Name :<input type="text" size="60" Id="txtacname" onblur="textempty()"    
name="txtacname"  maxlength="80" autofocus>
```

2] here javascript function in js file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var x=document.getElementById("myform");
  x.addEventListener("blur",textempty,true);

  function textempty(id)
  {
    var tid=("#" + id);
    window.alert(tid);
  }
});
```

Comment: Confused about what you want to do here, just pass the name to the function you only have one textbox in the form

Comment: You've got 2 event handlers one inline (`onblur="textempty()"`) and one added via the `addEventListener`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: but if i use only inline (onblur="textempty()")  the function is not working insdie js file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to send the id as a parameter.

```
Name :<input type="text" size="60" Id="txtacname" onblur="textempty('txtacname')"    
name="txtacname"  maxlength="80" autofocus>
```

Answer (score 0):

see this example http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/380L9w5c/1/

using jquery

```
$('input[type="text"]').blur(function(){
  console.log($(this).attr('id'))
})
```

In your code your are using **$( document ).ready()** so i think you are using jquery so jquery will help you and it is very easy

Answer (score 0):

With pure js, simply update the parameter to `textempty(this.id)`:

```js
var textempty = function(id) {
  alert(id);
};
```

```html
Name :
<input type="text" size="60" Id="txtacname" onblur="textempty(this.id);" name="txtacname" maxlength="80" autofocus>
```

With pure js, without parameter update:

```js
var textempty = function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  var id = (e.srcElement || e.target).id;
  alert(id);
};
```

```html
Name :
<input type="text" size="60" Id="txtacname" onblur="textempty();" name="txtacname" maxlength="80" autofocus>
```

With jquery:

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[type=text]').on('blur', textempty);
});

var textempty = function(e) {
  var id = this.id;
  alert(id);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Name :
<input type="text" size="60" Id="txtacname" name="txtacname" maxlength="80" autofocus>
```

Answer (score 0):

add a hidden field to the page and

```
function getValue(obj){
hiddenfieldid.value=obj.id ;  
  alert(obj.id);
  }
```

and on the server-side, you can get hidden field value